# Trying to set a prompt to display a specific portion of PWD in ZSH

Tags: zsh, ps1

I am currently using this in ZSH
`export PS1='${USER}:${PWD}: '`

I could use this:
`export PS1='${USER}:${PWD##*/} \$ '`

But I want to see a folder further up in the folder hierarchy, so I would like to use something like this,
`export PS1='${USER}:${PWD | cut -d '/' -f6}:${PWD##*/} '`

But this doesn't work it just shows this:
`${USER}:${PWD | cut -d / -f6}:${PWD##*/}`

I want it to show a specific folder (at positision f6) and then the current directory.

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?:

```
setopt prompt_subst
export PROMPT='${USER}:${${(s:/:)PWD}[5]}:${PWD:t} '
```

Some of the pieces:

- `setopt prompt_subst` - allows `${...}` in prompts to be expanded. You probably have this in your `~/.zshrc` already.
- `PROMPT` - same effect as `PS1`.
- `${(s:/:)PWD}` - splits the working directory value in `PWD` on `/`s.
- `${...[5]}` - selects the fifth element of that split (which correlates to the sixth field from `cut`).
- `${PWD:t}` - selects the 'tail' (last) element from the path.

The `s` parameter expansion flag is documented in the `zshexpn` man page, along with the `t` modifier.  You may also want to look at the prompt escapes described in the `zshmisc` man page, and the `precmd` hook in  `zshcontrib`.

Comment: Setopt doesn't seem to exist and the PROMPT parameter is ignored, I ended up just exporting PS1 with a return line instead to avoid the issue (the long directory above my command below).

Comment: @DavidHarman - thanks for looking at it. It sounds like your shell is set to `bash` and not `zsh`.

Comment: You are correct @Gairfowl, it is KSH, not ZSH, sorry about that....

Comment: @DavidHarman - no worries. If you are still looking for an answer that works in `ksh`, you'll probably have better luck posting a new question.